# How can I increase 5000 concurrent request with mpm_prefork on Apache

Tags: centos

I've configured Apache web server on my CentOs sever machine. I want to increase 5000 concurrent request with MPM_Prefork. Please suggest best Prefork configuration for that. I've done Prefork configuration on httpd.conf file, but its not working.

My Prefork configuration:

```
<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
    StartServers                5
    MinSpareServers             30
    MaxSpareServers             40
    MaxClients                  5000
    ServerLimit                 20
    MaxRequestsPerChild         500
</IfModule>

    KeepAlive On
MaxKeepAliveRequests            5000
KeepAliveTimeout                5
```

Comment: Which version of apache?

Comment: This should be on serverfault, not stackoverflow.  Also with a bit of research you will find TONS of information on Apache prefork configuration (beyond the official documentation.  http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/

Comment: Using Apache 2.4.6. I found huge information related with Prefork & I've configured too, but when I check load test with Siege tool, its getting only 1000 request at a time. I want 5000 concurrent request. Please suggest.....

Comment: I've 16 gb RAM on my server. I've increased my ServerLimit as well. But didnt work. Please suggest.....

Answer (score 0):

Some suggestions.

- **MaxRequestsPerChild** if your apache is stable, you can increase that one to a MUCH higher value.  This prevents your children processes from dying to often. I have a web site set at 10 000 (high volume).
- **MaxClients** (renamed **MaxRequestsWorkers**) is set to 5000, but **ServerLimit** is at 20.  So MaxRequestsWorkers is blocked at 20.  ServerLimit is the highest MaxRequestsWorkers will be allowed to grow.  So put ServerLimit higher.
- You said your tests showed 1000 requests at a time with **ServerLimit** == 20.  So do not set ServerLimit to 5000!
- If you expect high traffic, increase **StartServer** so it will be ready.
- When you perform your tests, ramp up the load up to it's maximum, then let it sit there for a while.  Do not try 5000 at one go.
- Setup server-status in your apache.  This will allow you to view the state of your Apache (number of workers, what they are doing, ...).  If you see all workers busy and have still not reached your 5000, increase the values accordingly.
- And finaly realise that 5000 concurrent requests means 5000 browser actively requesting data *at the same time*, with an open connection.  Real users have think time, read time so your requests are staggered more than with a load testing tool.